# Typescript: undefined static variable issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't understand why the next issue happens. Code with the same structure works fine in any other object-oriented languages like C# or Java.
I am writing Node.Js app using Typescript.

So I have a class `ServiceLocator` with two static variables:

```
//ServiceLocator.ts
export class ServiceLocator {
    public static dataRepository: IDataRepository = new DataRepository();
    public static authService: IAuthService = new AuthService();
}
```

Class from the second one variable using the first one static variable. This how it looks:

```
//AuthService.ts
const dataRepository: IDataRepository = ServiceLocator.dataRepository;
export class AuthService implements IAuthService {
...
}
```

But once I am trying to get `authService` link like this:

```
//AuthController.ts
const authService: IAuthService = ServiceLocator.authService;
export class AuthController {

    public async signIn(request: Request, response: Response) {
        ..
    }
..
}
```

I got an error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataRepository' of undefined
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Did you import the `ServiceLocator` in `AuthController.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference here.  In order to construct the `AuthService` *module* you need a fully constructed `ServiceLocator` class.  However, JavaScript needs a fully constructed `AuthService` module in order to construct the `ServiceLocator` class.  Switching the order of instantiation would simply result in an error from `ServiceModule <cint>` (to coin a Java-ism) along the lines of "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a constructor".

The solution is to simply make the dependency lazy:

```
//AuthService.ts
const dataRepositoryReference: IDataRepository = import('./ServiceLocator')
  .then(({ ServiceLocator }) => ServiceLocator.dataRepository);
export class AuthService implements IAuthService {
  public async findUserByUsername(username: UserName) {
    const dataRepository = await dataRepositoryReference;
    // ... snip ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine but then I need to create repository reference in each method. This will provide a lot of code duplication as far as I have a few such references. Do you have any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: This is how I trying to do that without method integration. But obviously, it looks not pretty good for me. What do you think? https://codeshare.io/5zk7r4

Comment: Using a side effect to set the binding asynchronously is a recipe for random null pointer exceptions (when `findByUsername` gets executed before `.then({ xValue }) => xBinding = xValue)`).  You can make it a little better by keeping the promise around and using it as a latch (but that's almost as fragile without a lint rule).